# Redirect URL with mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect this type of link:

```
http:example/categories/subcat1,122
```

to this type:

```
http:example/categories/cat1/subcat1
```

For every cat2 there will be one cat1 that i will insert on rewrite rules.e.g for:

```
http:example/categories/subcat2,324
```

i need

```
http:example/categories/cat2/subcat2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(katigories)/(aggeioxeiroyrgoi), /$1/ygeia/$2? [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# rest of your rewrite rules go below
```

Comment: I try to use rewrite rule for this link: " http:example.com/katigories/aggeioxeiroyrgoi,139 " trying to convert it to: " http:example.com/katigories/ygeia/aggeioxeiroyrgoi " but is not working

Comment: I use this rule " RewriteRule ^(katigories)/(aggeioxeiroyrgoi)(\d+), /$1/ygeia$/$2$3 [L,NC,NE,R=301] "

Comment: Yes now is working! Excellent! Just one question if i need to do the same redirect but without folder "katigories" what is the rule i must use? e.g: " http:example.com/katigories/ygeia/aggeioxeiroyrgoi " must be http:example.com/ygeia/aggeioxeiroyrgoi

Comment: That rule would be: `RewriteRule ^katigories/(aggeioxeiroyrgoi), /ygeia/$1? [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! You help me a lot!